# Python read 1 column of Excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl, attributeerror

I'm trying to use `openpyxl` to read 1 column out of a Excel-file until it hits an empty cell, then it needs to stop. But i don't get it working. This is my code so far:

```
import openpyxl
import os

def main():
    filePath = os.getcwd() + "\file.xlsx"

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filePath, read_only=True)
    sheet = wb["Sheet1"]


    for row in range(sheet.max_row):
        if(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value == None):
            break
        print(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But this results in the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "someProgram.py", line 27, in  main()
>   File "someProgram.py", line 15, in main
>   if(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value == None):
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 349,
>   in cell coordinate = coordinate.upper().replace('$', '')
>   AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: Why don't you use pandas?

Comment: What is pandas??

Comment: It's a library in which you can manipulate countless number of data formats including excel.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try it out

Comment: The error points to the openpyxl library im using, so i think im using it wrong, but i don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Your code doesn't run as shown: `deltaPath` is not defined. Please post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry that needs to be filePath

Comment: see my answer below @SandervTilburg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python openpyxl read until emtpy cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365992/python-openpyxl-read-until-emtpy-cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value == None):
```

`sheet.cell` is expecting to have a `str` cell name such as `A1` and not of type `int` for one parameter function.

You need to specify the `row` and `column` keys such as:

```
sheet.cell(row=row+1, column=1).value
```

if you specify an `int` type `row` and `column` variables

Comment: Thanks! i have changed it to `heet.cell(row=row+1, column=1).value == "")` and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I see that I am able to print all the values in the column using the same code but with slight modification to below line: (basically, escape '\' character by adding one more \

```
import openpyxl
import os

def main():
    filePath = os.getcwd() + "\\file.xlsx"
    print(filePath)
    print(os.getcwd)
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=filePath, read_only=True)
    sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
    for row in range(sheet.max_row):
        if(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value == None):
            break
        print(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a small xlsx file myself with only one column filled with integers in the following order: 5, 4, 3, 2, 10 and 11. The code below seems to work for, for me at least:

```
column_index = 0 # 0 = A, 1 = B, ...
sheet_name = "Sheet1"
sheet = wb[sheet_name]

for r in sheet.rows:
    value = r[column_index].value
    print("value",value)
    if value is None:
        break
```

Output:

```
value 5
value 4
value 3
value 2
value 10
value 11
```

If I delete one intermediate value in that column, say 2, then the loop stops, like so:

```
value 5
value 4
value 3
value None
```

I hope this helps with your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an iterator which will be handier in such situations.

```
wb = load_workbook(pathToYourFile, use_iterators=True)
sheet = wb.worksheets["Sheet1"]
row_count = sheet.max_row
for row in range(sheet.max_row):
        if(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value == None):
            break
        print(sheet.cell(row+1,1).value)
```