# How to find next empty cell on a specific column and write to it?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to find the next empty cell in a specific column and write to values that cell. I've tried it using following method:

```
for row in sheet['A{}:A{}'.format(sheet.min_row,sheet.max_row)]:
    if row is None:
        sheet.cell(column=1).value = name
    else:
        print ("Cell have data")
```

But It's not writing data to next empty cell. How can I fix that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python openpyxl read until empty cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365992/python-openpyxl-read-until-empty-cell)

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for the guidance. The thread that you mentioned doesn't contain the data writing part. I want to figure out how to write data to that empty cell.

Comment: `row` will never be `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty pointless to construct a string with `min_row` and `max_row`. You can simply access the whole column:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("book.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for cell in ws["A"]:
    if cell.value is None:
        cell.value = "new value2"

wb.save("book.xlsx")
```

But this reads the whole column at once as a tuple. Instead, you can use [`iter_rows()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) (`iter_cols()` is not available in read-only):

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("book.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1):
    cell = row[0]
    if cell.value is None:
        cell.value = "new value"

wb.save("book.xlsx")
```

Comment: I've tried both mentioned methods. But they haven't written " new value "in the empty cell. I can't figure out what's the reason for that.

Comment: Are you `save`ing in the end? To the same file? Even though this code is short and simple I tested it and it works

Comment: Yeah I have written the saving line.In workbook 4th cell is empty and I want to write to that cell.

Comment: I've checked the code. I think It doesn't work when values are already existing on the worksheet.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to remember that the loops I show are not infinite (as is Excel's nature), they only go until `max_rows`. So you can't write a new maximum value this way. Only missing values