# openpyxl script skips rows when appending to second column of spreadsheet

Tags: openpyxl

I am writing a small script to fill values time and power values for 2 modules in a spreadsheet. Column A and C would store Time and Power values for Module 1 while Column B and D would store time and power values for module 2. I am having difficulties with appending values to the initial rows of the second module. Any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
# get user inputs
try:
    step_size = float(self.step_size_entry.get())
    hold_time = float(self.hold_time_entry.get())
    upper_bound = float(self.upper_bound_entry.get())
    lower_bound = float(self.lower_bound_entry.get())
    ramping = self.ramping_var.get()
    selected_module = self.selected_module_var.get()



# create excel workbook and sheet
try:
   wb = load_workbook("Test.xlsx")
   if "data" in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb["data"]
   else:
        # add another sheet to the workbook
        sheet = wb.create_sheet("data")
except FileNotFoundError:
   wb = Workbook()
   sheet = wb.active
   sheet.title = "data"

# check if "data" sheet already exists
   if "data" in wb.sheetnames:
       sheet = wb["data"]
   else:
       # add another sheet to the workbook
       sheet = wb.create_sheet("data")

# populate header row
sheet["A1"] = "Time 1"
sheet["B1"] = "Time 2"
sheet["C1"] = "Module 1"
sheet["D1"] = "Module 2"


# initialize variables
power = lower_bound
prev_power = None

# get the index of the last filled row for Module 1
last_row_m1 = len(sheet['A'])
last_row_m2 = len(sheet['B'])
# get the index of the last filled row for Module 2


# Calculate time_1 and time_2
if last_row_m1 > 1:
    time_1 = (sheet.cell(row=last_row_m1, column=1).value) + (sheet.cell(row=last_row_m1, column=1).value - sheet.cell(row=last_row_m1- 1, column=1).value)
else:
    time_1 = 1

if last_row_m2 > 1:
    time_2_prev_value = sheet.cell(row=last_row_m2, column=2).value
    if time_2_prev_value is None:
         time_2_prev_value = 0
    time_2 = time_2_prev_value + hold_time
else:
    time_2 = 1



# if the sheet is empty, set last_row to 0
if last_row_m1 == 1 and sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value is None:
    last_row_m1 = 0

if last_row_m2 == 1 and sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value is None:
    last_row_m2 = 0


# populate power column based on ramping selection
if ramping == "Ascending" and selected_module == "Module 1":
    while power <= upper_bound:
        for i in range(int(hold_time)):
            if power != prev_power:  # Add row only if power value is changing
                sheet.append([time_1, None, power, None])
                prev_power = power
            time_1 = time_1 + hold_time
        power += step_size
    
if ramping == "Ascending" and selected_module == "Module 2":
    while power <= upper_bound:
        for i in range(int(hold_time)):
            if power != prev_power:  # Add row only if power value is changing
                sheet.append([None, time_2, None, power])
                prev_power = power
            time_2 = time_2 + hold_time
        power += step_size

# save and close workbook
wb.save("Test.xlsx")
wb.close()


#User Input 1:
#step_size = 10
#hold_time = 5
#upper_bound = 120
#lower_bound = 100
#ramping = "Ascending"
#selected_module = "Module 1"

#User Input 2:
#step_size = 10
#hold_time = 5
#upper_bound = 120
#lower_bound = 100
#ramping = "Ascending"
#selected_module = "Module 2"
```

### Current output:

| Time 1 | Time 2 | Power 1 | Power 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blank | 100 | blank |
| 6 | blank | 110 | blank |
| 11 | blank | 120 | blank |
| blank | 1 | blank | 100 |
| blank | 6 | blank | 110 |
| blank | 11 | blank | 120 |

### Desired output:

| Time 1 | Time 2 | Power 1 | Power 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 | 100 | 100 |
| 10 | 10 | 110 | 110 |
| 15 | 15 | 120 | 120 |
| blank | blank | blank | blank |
| blank | blank | blank | blank |
| blank | blank | blank | blank |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mdeF.png)

Comment: It helps to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can assist with your issue. There are a number of undefined variables in your code that would make it impossible to run the code sample and require speculating on what the code does. Also while there is samples of the output there appears to be no details on what the input data is.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I have added some more lines to the code for more context. I also added user inputs and reworked the current and desired user outputs. The main difficulty I am facing is with appending the values to the appropiate rows. 

to answer your second commet; yes, the while loop for last_row_m2 was intended to find the last used line for column B (time 2)

For your third qusestion/comment, I have reworked the code but it still does not provide the desired results. Not sure what I am doign wrong here

Comment: I also added a screenshot of the excel output. The numbers in red is what I would like the values to be placed at but can't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: You are using `sheet.append()`, which will find the last row with any data and add data to the row below that. This is the reason for you getting the rows with blanks... only cols A, C or B,D will be filled. You need to get a single column, find the first blank row and write to it. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66196804/how-to-find-next-empty-cell-on-a-specific-column-and-write-to-it). Let me know if you are still not able to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit, makes it easier to show examples.

As @Redox mentions in his comment, your issue with alignment is due to your use of append.
As indicated append **always** adds to the next after the last used row
e.g. if the last used row was 10 and I 'sheet append' some data it will be placed on row 11. If I do another 'sheet append' it will be placed on row 12 and the next append, row 13 etc.
So in order to add the 'second' set of data (after the first is added) you **cannot** use 'sheet append'. You can only individually add the values to the required cells.

**Note also**
Length of a column does not return the last used row of the specified column, rather it will be the last used row for the whole sheet. Therefore these lines; 
`last_row_m1 = len(sheet['A'])` and `last_row_m2 = len(sheet['B'])`
will return the same value which will also be the same value as what you get from `sheet.max_row`.
To get the last used row for a specific column you could use a list comprehension like this assuming rows are filled, (e.g. for Column 'A');

```
last_row_m1 = [x.row for x in sheet['A'] if x.value is not None][-1]
```

I have included this in the code sample below and printed the values from the length method and list comprehension method. You can see in the printed output on the second run after the module 1 data has been written so that Col A and C have four rows (including the header), and B and D still only have the header;
The original length check for columns A and B and the sheet max row all show 4, whereas the actual length for column B is 1 as obtained from the list comprehension calculation.

```
Orig Last row m1 Col A: 4
Last row m1 Col A: 'last_row_m1': 4
Orig Last row m2 Col B: 4
Last row m2 Col B: 'last_row_m2': 1
Sheet last row: 'sheet_last_row: 4
```

I have made some modifications to your code that will produce what you intend. It intended as an example as it may not be completely adaptable into your real life application.
The main change is to allow for either method of adding the data either by append or cell by cell depending whether the data is added to new rows or inserted into existing used rows.
I've also changed adding data to be completed in the same block since the two blocks used are basically a code repetition.

For testing I have run the code once with the `### User Input 1:` data enabled and `### User Input 2:` data disabled and no existing workbook "Test.xlsx". Then enable `### User Input 2:` data and disable `### User Input 1:` data on the workbook produced in the first run.
I have also modified the block that sets the time_2 value so `time_2` will initialise with a value of 5 rather than 1 to differentiate the data set for Module 1 to Module 2 and duplicate the screenshot data provided.

```
time_2 = 5  # Modified for debug testing
```

In this code example the data in Columns A ('Time 1') and C ('Module 1') from '### User Input 1:' are added using append as this data is the first on the new row.
The data in Columns B ('Time 2') and D ('Module 2') from '### User Input 2:' are added by iterating the cells in the column for each row, also using a list.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook, Workbook

### Enable each input data set one after the other 
### User Input 1:
# step_size = 10
# hold_time = 5
# upper_bound = 120
# lower_bound = 100
# ramping = "Ascending"
# selected_module = "Module 1"

### User Input 2:
# step_size = 10
# hold_time = 5
# upper_bound = 120
# lower_bound = 100
# ramping = "Ascending"
# selected_module = "Module 2"

# create excel workbook and sheet
xlfile = 'Test.xlsx'
xlsheet = 'data'

try:
    wb = load_workbook(xlfile)
    if xlsheet in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[xlsheet]
    else:
        # add another sheet to the workbook
        sheet = wb.create_sheet(xlsheet)
except FileNotFoundError:
    wb = Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    sheet.title = xlsheet

    # check if required sheet already exists
    if xlsheet in wb.sheetnames:
        sheet = wb[xlsheet]
    else:
        # add another sheet to the workbook
        sheet = wb.create_sheet(xlsheet)

# populate header row
sheet["A1"] = "Time 1"
sheet["B1"] = "Time 2"
sheet["C1"] = "Module 1"
sheet["D1"] = "Module 2"

# initialize variables
power = lower_bound
prev_power = None

# Get the index of the last filled row for Module 1
orig_last_row_m1 = len(sheet['A'])
print(f"Orig Last row m1 Col A: {orig_last_row_m1}")
last_row_m1 = [x.row for x in sheet['A'] if x.value is not None][-1]
print(f"Last row m1 Col A: 'last_row_m1': {last_row_m1}")

# get the index of the last filled row for Module 2
orig_last_row_m2 = len(sheet['B'])
print(f"Orig Last row m2 Col B: {orig_last_row_m2}")
last_row_m2 = [x.row for x in sheet['B'] if x.value is not None][-1]
print(f"Last row m2 Col B: 'last_row_m2': {last_row_m2}")

### Get sheet max row
sheet_last_row = sheet.max_row
print(f"Sheet last row 'sheet_last_row: {sheet_last_row}")

# Calculate time_1 and time_2
if last_row_m1 > 1:
    time_1 = sheet.cell(row=last_row_m1, column=1).value + (
            sheet.cell(row=last_row_m1, column=1).value - sheet.cell(row=last_row_m1 - 1, column=1).value)
else:
    time_1 = 1

if last_row_m2 > 1:
    time_2_prev_value = sheet.cell(row=last_row_m2, column=2).value
    if time_2_prev_value is None:
        time_2_prev_value = 0
    time_2 = time_2_prev_value + hold_time
else:
    time_2 = 5  # Modified for debug testing

# if the sheet is empty, set last_row to 0
if last_row_m1 == 1 and sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value is None:
    last_row_m1 = 0

if last_row_m2 == 1 and sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value is None:
    last_row_m2 = 0

# populate power column based on ramping selection
# if ramping == "Ascending" and selected_module == "Module 1":

### Determine if both column A and B are equal length.
### If Column B is shorter than Column A set the row to 2 (next after Header row)
### Otherwise start a next unused row
if last_row_m2 < last_row_m1:
    row = 2
else:
    row = sheet_last_row

### If input data is 'module 1' set time to time1 otherwise set to time_2
time = time_1 if selected_module == "Module 1" else time_2

add_list = []

while power <= upper_bound:
    for i in range(int(hold_time)):
        if power != prev_power:  # Add row only if power value is changing
            ### Update the list of data to add depending on if we have 'Module 1' or 'Module 2'
            add_list = [time, None, power, None] if selected_module == "Module 1" else [None, time, None, power]

            ### If there is no data already entered in the block i.e. first insert the
            ### data can be added using append
            if sheet_last_row == 1:
                sheet.append(add_list)
            ### If data has already been entered in the sheet then must add data cell by cell
            else:
                ### Iterate the columns and enter the data from the list cell by cell
                for x in range(len(add_list)):
                    new_value = add_list[x]
                    if new_value is not None:
                        sheet.cell(row=row, column=x+1).value = new_value

            prev_power = power
            row += 1
        time = time + hold_time # Change time to be generic
    power += step_size


wb.save("Test.xlsx")
wb.close()
```

[image: Screen shot of output after Module 1 and Module 2 run]

Comment: Thank you so much for this man! You helped me get unstuck from a rut I was in for 2 whole days.